# What could spammers do to our video URLs in our video sitemaps?

Tags: seo

Google [states](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/video-sitemaps#video-sitemap-best-practices) that:

> If you want to prevent spammers from accessing your video content at the <player_loc> or <content_loc> URLs, verify that any bots accessing your server are really Googlebot.

I'm creating a video sitemap and I don't understand what abuse or harm spammers can do to my site using the links of my videos.

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Are these videos hosted directly / served on your site or is it an embed from a video service (i.e. youtube)? I can see, if they are hosted from your site, allowing spammers to constantly hit your videos could increase the bandwidth on your site and potentially DDoS your website. Also, most hosts probably have a tiered setup where they allow a specific data transfer limit. Could hit it pretty quick if spammers decided to hit your video pages hard and play them.